# How to make the elements of a list half in a list A and half in a list B?

Tags: apex

I would like to make two lists receive the halves of another list. So the first list has a random size, but it is never greater than 10 and is always greater than 5. I want to create the list half1 and list half2 so the list half1 receives the first 5 elements of the parent list and the list half2 receives the last 5 elements. At the moment my code looks like this:

```
         Integer half2;
         
          if(listSize>5){
             half2=listSize-5;
          for(Integer i=0; i<5;i++){
             listhalf1.add(list[i]);
          }
          for(Integer i=5; i<half2; i++){
            listhalf2.add(list[i]);
          }
             
         }
```

however this second for is not being executed, when adding the sysyem.debug in it nothing appears in the log... does anyone know where I'm going wrong? and if you have a better idea of ​​how to achieve this result I would also like to know :)

Comment: Example: If your `listSize` is `6`, then `half2` will equal `1`.  In this case your second `for` loop won't be entered because you start with `i=5` which is supposed to loop as long as`5 < half2`. Since 5 > 1, it doesn't enter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second loop is starting at i=5 and half2=5, so it won't execute. You can instead do:

```
for(Integer i=0; i<half2; i++){
  listhalf2.add(list[i+half2]);
}
```